# C# Winform How to Generate fix character?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, if-statement, for-loop

i make generate number 8,9,A,B (Int64)

**But i need**

00000008

00000009

0000000A

0000000B

000001ED

**this Code:**

```
        int count = 1;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT max(Numb) FROM tblAs");

        string sql = sb.ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = Conn;
        count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        int newCount = count;
        int i;


        for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                newCount = newCount + 1;

                Int64 numTag;
                string cTag = Convert.ToString(newCount);
                numTag = Int64.Parse(cTag);
                cTag = numTag.ToString("X");

                if (cTag.Length < 8)
                {
                    int countchar = 8 - cTag.Length;
                    for (i = 1; i <= countchar; i++)
                    {
                        cTag = "0" + cTag;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = cTag;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Error line:** dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = cTag;
**Message:** Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Thanks you for your time :)

Comment: row index starts from zero and not 1

Comment: In general, I think you should get to familiar with debugging tools. Most of the times, `just stepping into code, watching variables and comparing expected values and actual values in your head` does the trick. You would be amazed how quickly you find all the bugs in this code by doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save yourself some work and [use the built-in features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) of the .NET Framework:

```
// automatically pads the number with up to 8 leading zeros
cTag = numTag.ToString("X8");
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the same variable `i` for **nested** `for`s.

```
for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
```

and

```
for (i = 1; i <= countchar; i++)
```

This is why you get `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection`